# JSON in angular frontend

Tags: angular, mongodb, angular-forms

hi someone can help me to show my json in a frontend angular (like tree or extension)

this is my backend JSON it's a Buildings array grouped by campuses
to make relational mongodb dataBases.

```
    [
{
"_id": "campus4",
"buildings": [
{
"buildingName": "building7",
"phoneNumber": "00000000000"
},
{
"buildingName": "building8",
"phoneNumber": "000000000"
},
{
"buildingName": "building9",
"phoneNumber": "0000000000"
}
]
```

my get service :

```
  getBuildings() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/buildings`);
  }
```

my buildinglist.component.ts :

```
    ngOnInit() {
  this.fetchBuildings();
}

fetchBuildings() {
  this.gesroomService
    .getBuildings()
    .subscribe((data: Building[]) => {
      this.buildings = data;
      console.log('Building data requested...');
      console.log(this.buildings);
    });
}
```

Comment: have you something in angular that is requesting these data?

Comment: yes i have my service and my "buildinglist.component.ts"  where i can fetch the informations. i'll put the in my post. what i want is a component or html to show this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the first array, accessing `_id`.
Then you can iterate over `buildings` list.

Something like this should work

```
<div *ngFor="let bList of buildings">

    <div>_id: {{ bList._id }}</div>
    <div *ngFor="let b of bList.buildings">
         <div>buildingName: {{ b.buildingName }}</div>
         <div>phoneNumber: {{ b.phoneNumber }}</div>
    </div>

</div>
```